# Why is this function returning false?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
function lock() {
    if($lock = @fopen('lock.txt', 'x')) {
        fwrite($lock, getmypid());
        fclose($lock);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$response = lock();
```

When I run the code, the file lock.txt is created and the PID is put into the file. However, the function returns false. What in the world is going on?

- I need `X` for fopen because I'm using this function for file locking and control
- I took the `@` off and this is the error that I got:

> fopen(lock.txt): failed to open stream: File exists in /xxx on line
>   22.

The problem is, I know for sure that the file does not exist -- I even went back and deleted it before I ran the code. The code creates the file but still returns false.

I checked to make sure no other code is creating the file. I even waited 30 secs to wait and see if the file reappeared -- it does not appear by itself, it only appears after I execute this code.

Comment: Is it being called exactly one time?

Comment: Take off the `@`, do you get an error message?

Comment: As per [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), `fopen` with `x` mode returns `false` if the file already exists. Are you sure you are making changes to it? I somehow doubt it...

Comment: using `@` is the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Removed @, updated OP with new info.

Comment: What code are you using to determine it is returning `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) states that for mode `x`:

> Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. This is equivalent to specifying O_EXCL|O_CREAT flags for the underlying open(2) system call.

The function is returning false because `@fopen('lock.txt', 'x')` returns false (the file would already exist), which causes `$lock = @fopen('lock.txt', 'x')` to evaluate to false, triggering the branch to `return false;`.

Comment: Remove the error suppression character `@` and run it again. It'll give you an error message. While you're at it, make sure that the script is executing in the directory you think it is (a script can live in `/data/script/` but run in `/run/other/directory`).

Comment: That file is being created between you deleting it and the script running. Check that you don't have any other code that could write to that same file.

Comment: I also put in the whole file path itself to make sure it isn't checking for the file in a different directory -- same issue.

Comment: Checked, no code is creating it. I even wait 30 secs to wait and see if the file reappeared. No cigar. Could this be related to file permissions by chance?

Comment: Could be, although if the error states that the file exists, not that it can't access it.

Comment: Are there any quirk with fclose? I'm thinking the issue is there because the code executes up to fwrite($lock, getmypid()).

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, it looks like the issue is with the fopen part. Ugh this is so frustrating, the answer is probably really simple.

Comment: Change the value of the locking file, put the full path to the file, make sure you only call the lock function once (or clean up after each call). Try these both one at the time and together. It should help you debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` mode `X` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

> Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call
>   will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level
>   E_WARNING.

**If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING.**

You will see the warning if you don't use `@` error suppression.

You probably want mode `W`.

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the
>   file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist,
>   attempt to create it.

Comment: I need x because I'm using this as a quasi file lock function

Comment: Then you'll need to delete it before calling `lock()` again.

Comment: I have a delete function in place that will be called to delete the file when I'm done locking. However, I'm first trying to make sure this part of the function works. This lock() is not in a loop, it runs just once, so the lack of deleting the file is not the issue.